# How can copy/paste formula cell as hyperlink in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to copy a formula cell that generates hyperlinks from cell content using some formula. Now when I try to "copy" and "paste value" that formula to another Excel file I am not getting the hyperlink, only plain text after I do Paste special > Paste Values. I tried all the options of Paste Special but none of them paste the values as hyperlinks.
However, if I first copy/paste cell values to Word and then copy from Word and paste them into Excel I get the cell values as hyperlinks.

Example:

```
Content of Cell A1 = Try it » (https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_regexp_i)

Content of Formula cell B1 = HYPERLINK(MID(A1,SEARCH("(",A1)+1,SEARCH(")",A1)-SEARCH("(",A1)-1),LEFT(A1, SEARCH(" (", A1) - 1))
```

Is there any way to copy the formula cell value as a hyperlink directly from one Excel to another or between two Excel sheets of the same Excel file as I can replicate the same issue using one Excel file using sheet1 and sheet2?

[image]

Comment: Does this answers your question? [Unable to copy formulas from one excel workbook to new excel sheet](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unable-to-copy-formulas-from-one-excel-workbook-to/397609e0-ced1-43fb-9dfd-e4c3c2d1232e)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Justinas, the problem is not related to two instances of excel, I have the same issue if I copy and paste it from sheet1 to sheet2 of the same excel file. I will modify the question to state that.